# Как установить intel hd graphics в Ubuntu 18.04 LTS из под VitrualBox на Windows 7?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Есть хостовая ос windown 7 x64 и гостевая ось Ubuntu desktop 18.04 lts. Средство виртуализации - virtual Box. 
На хостовой ос стоит гиперпень g5400. Если запустить гостевую ос даже с браузером не получается без лагов работать, а уж видео просмотреть тем более.

Как установить драйвера но Ubuntu, чтобы решить приведенные проблемы?

Comment: Просто установить VirtualBox Guest Additions, это во-первых. А во-вторых, вы уверены, что проблема именно в видео, а не в процессоре и не в оперативной памяти?

Comment: процессорной мощи хватит, 1 ядро - 3700 Мгц и 1 гБ оЗУ, везде лаги, любое окно откроешь и лаги, тут видео и видеодрайвера. 
Кстати, additions установлены, но без толку

А когда я ставил XP все круто сразу отрабатывало... А щас никак

Comment: Одним из признаков корректно установленных additions является автоматическая подгонка разрешения виртуального экрана убунты под размер окна с виртуалкой при его изменении. У вас такое поведение наблюдается?

Comment: как оказалось, аддоны не установились нормально. с графикой стало чуть лучше но не более и да - авто подгонки разрешения не случилось.

попутно были установлены gcc и make, на что он реагировал изначально, а вот следующая ошибка не понята...

получаю ошибку следующего вида при установка дополнений. сам виртуал бокс версии 4.3.12
https://habrastorage.org/webt/tu/8z/ha/tu8zhabxpdmivq57-zpcwve06ym.png

Comment: Ну вот вы собственно и `Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong`, не стесняйтесь

Comment: спасибо, пошел разведать это дело

Comment: А вообще VirtualBox 4.3.12 как-то староват, уже давно есть 5.2 и новее

Comment: Я использовал разные версии 5.1.xx & 5.2.xx, но они почему то не работают стабильно. Один раз создаешь вм, оно работает ровно до следующего перезапуска или работает только win XP. Никакие 7, убунту и тд не работают. Описанные на форумах (одни и те же по большей части) способы не сработали и последним вариантом был прыжок назад на одну из стабильных версий: 4.3.12 или 4.3.10. 
Если в общем не все будет хорошо с виртуал бокс попробую VMware...

Comment: Ну а старый виртуалбокс может запросто не поддерживать новую убунту (на что он, в общем-то, уже намекнул в вашем скриншоте). Ну а лично у меня все версии работали стабильно

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки! 
возьму 5.2 или одну из 5.1 и попробую по новой
Если возможно перевидите это в ответ. Отмечу как решение

Answer (score 0):

Гостевая система в Oracle VirtualBox не нуждается в настройке видеодрайверов - если они стоят в основной системе, то проблем быть не должно. 
Скорее всего, вы просто не настроили количество выделяемой под виртуальную машину видеопамяти - сделать это можно, отредактировав конфигурацию.

Comment: странно, но у меня ни разу это хорошо не работало.
http://prntscr.com/lfkdaz 
вот, добавил памяти...
результат тот же, никакой плавности, как будто в 2000 год попал с виндоус 95

Comment: @GermanMartin а оперативки сколько выделено и сколько видеопамяти? Там от 2 Гб ОП и от 1 Гб видюхи.

Comment: 1 Гб Оперативки + 128 Мб видюхи. У меня pentium g5400

Comment: @GermanMartin вот-вот. Ubuntu даже 512 Мб видеопамяти мало. Установите Xubuntu.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский с чего бы это вдруг мало?

Comment: @andreymal он даже DE не менял.  Gnome 3 жрет как не в себя 

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский просто память — может быть, но не видеопамять же наверно?

Comment: @andreymal да, тут, скорее, дело в ОЗУ.

Comment: то есть со встройки у меня ничего не получится хотите сказать?
Может быть тут есть обладатели Pentium Gxxxx четырехпоточных, чтобы пролить на это свет?

Comment: https://hsto.org/webt/rt/kb/7g/rtkb7gby1p-fiwsqyzxs6hknsfm.png
все что есть, попробую еще потыкать

Comment: Гугл дал инфу, что тут давали убунту 'Под нее при установки выделил 2 ядра процессора ( у меня I6400 intel) , 4 гига оперативной памяти, 64 мегабайт видеопамяти, включил 3d ускорение.' и хоть бы что - это как бы намекает, что дело не в этом.